# STM32F103C8 writing driver and can't change register bit value

Tags: embedded, stm32, cortex-m, mcu, rcc

this is my code, when I try to change ADC1 register bit I change address of ADC and offset and it works well.
but when I wan to change ADC CR2 value it doesn't work. when I run this code, ADC2 is enabled but CONT value is 0. [image]

I tried to enable all ADC2 register values to 1 using for loop but no one change values all are 0.

Code :

```
#include <stdint.h>

#define RCC_BASE_ADDR       0x40021000UL
#define RCC_APB2_ENR_OFFSET 0x18UL
#define RCC_APB2_ENR_ADDR   (RCC_BASE_ADDR + RCC_APB2_ENR_OFFSET)

#define ADC_BASE_ADDR       0x40012800UL
#define ADC_CR2_ENR_OFFSET  0x08UL
#define ADC_CR2_ENR_ADDR    (ADC_BASE_ADDR + ADC_CR2_ENR_OFFSET)

int main()
{
  //write address values in variable
  uint32_t *pRccApb2Enr = (uint32_t *)RCC_APB2_ENR_ADDR;
  uint32_t *pAdcCr2Reg  = (uint32_t *)ADC_CR2_ENR_ADDR;
  
  //enable peripheral clock for ADC1
  *pRccApb2Enr |= (1<<10);
  //enable CONT bit
  *pAdcCr2Reg |= (1<<1);
  
  while(1);
  
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Don't post pictures of code.

Comment: @Clifford You are right, the source of the test program should be provided as code in the question. However, the relevant part of the screenshot is the view "Registers 1" to demonstrate the effect.

Comment: @thebusybee. Yes, in this case the image is useful as a demonstration of the _result_ and is useful.  A question that starts _"this is my code"_ should also have the code.  For the OP: the code as text allows, it to be included in an answer without laborious transcription.

Comment: Not shown in the image is the resulting state of RCC_AHBENR that should be checked too.

Comment: first I copy code to question but there was an error

Comment: @GiGeNCo. You can edit the question.  Use the code mark-up button or mark-down syntax.  It would be a pretty poor coding site if you could not post code.  You have posted another question with code, though I note that there someone corrected the post for you.  Take a little time to learn how to use the site perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that the lack of `volatile` and the fact that code is optimised (suggested by the "locals" showing as  "unavailable"), is probably the cause of your problem.

Defining your own register definitions is unnecessary, ill-advised, and error prone.  The vendor supplied header (stm32f1xx.h) is far safer.

In this case you have pointers that are written to but never read, and not declared `volatile`, so the compiler does nothing (as an optimisation). The compiler does not know that the pointers refer to registers, rather than simply regular memory.

Comment: Note I'd have usefully included corrected code in this answer, but am not prepared to transcribe your _picture_ of code manually.